# How to change taxonomy ordering in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

I am using Orchard CMS. I want to change the ordering of taxonomy items. Now it's ordering alphabetical. How can to change its ordering to be based on create date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Query` and sort it based on `create date` and then use this query to create a `Projection`. And you can use this `ProjectionItem` as a `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomy terms are sorted by the weight, as you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trHwX.png) image.

If the taxonomy term "A" has weight 8 and the taxonomy term "B" has weight 7, the term "A" will appear before term "B".